# Telegram: Is it possible for a human to take over in a bot conversation?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

A local foundation had setup Tawk.to for subscription questions and requests, but the widget on its website dissapeared all of a sudden. People sent their questions and if they wanted to subscribe, an operator would ask them some questions and fill forms to start the subscription process.

Looking for an (free) alternative to tawk.to, I remembered Telegram bots and learned about Dialogflow, so there's a way to make a Telegram bot reply with natural language understanding. Alas, the subscription process has to be done by hand, so whenever a user wants to subscribe, someone has to answer them, ask questions and fill the forms.

So I wonder if its possible to someone (say, bot's account owner) to take over a bot conversation with a user if they ask for a subscription and chat with them - some sort of what @BotSupport does.

Comment: Users' interactions with your bot can have different states. and you can choose which states your bot should answer it directly or it should forward the message to a support account and send the user's response once it got reply from support

Comment: You need a back-end program to monitor and handle the conversation and give control to the human whenever he wants.